# app_label permission problem Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-permissions

i've changed the app label doing this

```
class Model(models.Model):
     pass

     class Meta:
          app_label = 'App Name'
          db_table = 'app_table'
```

The table and application already existed, the problem is that when i go to the admin interface, only the superusers can view the app, and other users not, i tried to add permissions to the other user but it does not appear in the permissions box.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This Django ticket is relevant to your question (and my answer) you may want to check it out: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11154

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely a bug in Django. There's a conflict between the permission app_label and the contenttype app_label, result in the permission never matching in the admin. As a workaround until this is fixed, you can simply explicitly grant permission on the `ModelAdmin`:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return request.user.has_perm('app_label.add_modelclass')

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return request.user.has_perm('app_label.change_modelclass')

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return request.user.has_perm('app_label.delete_modelclass')
```

Where `app_label` is the `app_label` of the root model and `modelclass` is the lowercase name of your proxy model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're using app_label as it is intended here. If you're trying to improve the readability of your model's name, use [verbose_name](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.verbose_name) in your model's meta class.

[app_label](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.app_label) doesn't seem to have the best documentation, but from what I can tell it's supposed to be a machine readable name.

Comment: i need to put that table in another app group in Django Admin.

Comment: ah, I see. Apologies for the assumption... I've never tried to manipulate the admin listing quite like this. If you've got the "App Name" you mention matching the module name of the app group you want to move it to, you'll probably need to hack at the records in the permissions and or contenttypes database tables directly. But that's not an approach I'd take lightly. I'd consider overriding the admin templates first...

Answer (score 0):

`app_label` affects database table name and contenttype entries. As if your model wold be moved to other application. Permissions depend on contenttpyes. Syncdb will fix contenttypes, will create new tables, will create new permissions entries. You need to add permissions to existing users/groups on that model which was "moved" to other app.

Comment: the problem is that the permissions not are in permissions box of admin panel

Comment: did you run syncdb after you have changed `app_label`?

Comment: Maybe you are using south? you might need to add run syncdb with `--all` flag if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

Define your Model class as your normally would, ie:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
     pass

     class Meta:
          db_table = 'app_table'
```

Then create a Proxy Model, and change the App Label of that proxy model, for a 2nd model which looks like:

```
class MyProxyModel(MyModel):
     pass

     class Meta:
          proxy = True
          app_label = 'app_name'
```

Note: Your App label should be all lower case and contain underscores insead of spaces, Django will replace the underscores and capitalize the app label automatically.

Then register for the proxy model whatever ModelAdmin you have created.

```
admin.site.register(MyProxyModel,MyModelAdmin)
```

This should get your the MyModelAdmin to show up under a different App label in the Admin Interface. *I am not positive this will fix the permissions problem because I don't have an environment to test it in right now, but it will show up under the other other label.*